# How to geocode addresses by gmaps4rails and save coordinates in array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, mongoid, gmaps4rails

I'm using gem [mongoid_special](https://github.com/ryanong/mongoid_spacial) instead of [mongoid_geo](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/mongoid-geo). Main question is how to geocode with [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) entered places and save coordinates like lat and lng in right [mongoid_special](https://github.com/ryanong/mongoid_spacial) array fields? I predict many association for coordinates. Illustrative materials:

```
/haml view fields (autocompleted with google places)/
= f.text_field :from, :id => 'from'
= f.text_field :waypoints, :id => 'waypoints'
= f.text_field :to, :id => 'from'

class Trip
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  field :from, :type => String
  field :waypoints, type => String
  field :to, type => String

  field :from_coordinate, type: Array, spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }
  field :to_coordinate, type: Array, spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }

  embeds_many :coordinates
end

class Coordinates
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  field :coordinates, type: Array, spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }

  embedded_in :trip
end
```

Further question is how to get reverse geocode from this fields and display data as google direction?

**EDIT** Thanks for hint my solution for from field below, with the rest I can manage somehow.

```
before_save :from

def from=(from)
   self.from_coordinate = Gmaps4rails.geocode(from).first
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I suggest:

- To get the data the way you want, create your own `before_save` filter and use the `Gmaps4rails.geocode` method [described here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Methods).
- To display direction, [see here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Direction)
- no reverse geocoding is available in gmaps4rails